# how to foreach the json array in laravel php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

this is my array `[{"total":"03:00:00"},{"total":"08:00:00"},{"total":"04:00:00"}]` which is result of a query :

```
$total_hrs = UserDetails::where('userId','=', $id->selectRaw('time((TIMEDIFF( logged_out_time, logged_in_time ))) as total')->get();
```

And my view :

```
<tr>
  @for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++)
    <td style="height:50px;"> {{$i}}<br>
    @foreach ($dt as $key => $dz)
      @if(Carbon\Carbon::parse($dz)->day == $i)
       
        @foreach ($total_hrs as $h)
          {{$h["total"]}}
        @endforeach
     
      @endif
    @endforeach
    </td>
  @endfor
</tr>
```

In my view whole data result is coming.I want only one by one data wrt to date.

Desired Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdM1U.png)

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Are you missing json_decode? Try @foreach (json_decode($total_hrs) as $h)

Comment: @Marko yes i have used json decode in controller.But still not able to fetch the value one by one.

Comment: @NicoHaase actually i want one by one values from array [total] but i am getting all three values for one 'dt' .'[dt] is array of dates.So for one particular date ->one total hours value  .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but your $total_hrs foreach loop will always output all 3 values because there is no condition inside the loop. Are you missing an IF statement? Edit your question and give a desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$weekMap = [
    0 => 'MO',
    1 => 'TU',
    2 => 'WE',
    3 => 'TH',
    4 => 'FR',
    5 => 'SA',
    6 => 'SU',
];
<tr>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
         <th>$weekMap[$i]</th>
    @endfor
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="height:50px;"> 
        <div>{{$i}}</div>
        @foreach ($dt as $key => $dz)  
           @if(Carbon\Carbon::parse($dz)->day == $i)
             <div> 
             @foreach ($total_hrs as $h)
                 <span>{{$h->total}}</span>    // this will print 03:00:00 08:00:00 04:00:00
             @endforeach
             </div>
           @endif
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks.But  I want 03:00:00 for date 3feb, 08:00:00 for date 4feb like this for particular.

Comment: In that case you will have to store time logs according to the date on your database. If you already have done that then get the date as well with time logs.

Now you just compare the date and print the respective time logs on that date. :D

Comment: I would appreciate your vote on the answer. :)